# What is the correct way to update a person or group column with multiple items?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, spfx, error, react

I don't know what im doing wrong, but I keep getting this error.

ERROR:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error making HttpClient request in queryable [400]  ::> {"odata.error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The expression \"web/lists/getByTitle('TicketList')/items(3fdc0cce-fd24-48a2-b9ec-f536eea1ce4e)\" is not valid."}}}
    at new t (parsers.ts:132:9)
    at Function.<anonymous> (parsers.ts:138:16)
    at tslib.es6.js:102:23
    at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:83:53)
    at a (tslib.es6.js:73:58)
```

[image]

My code:

```
  // onChange/onSelect people picker
  const selectNewTeamMember = (user: any) => {
    sp.web.siteUsers.getByEmail(user.EntityData.Email).get().then(userData => {
      setTeamMembersIdArr((prevState: any) => {
        return [...prevState, userData.Id]
      })
    })
  }

useEffect(() => {
    if (teamMembersIdArr) {
      const listName = ListNames().TicketList
      const list = sp.web.lists.getByTitle(listName)
      list.items.getById(ticketGuid).update({
        TeamMembers: { results: teamMembersIdArr }
      })
    }
  }, [submitNewTeamMember, selectNewTeamMember])
```

GOALS:

- I am trying to get an array of id's, and then update the sharepoint column with those id's
- teamMembersIdArr is getting properly updated with the id's so i dont think that's the problem.
- My guess is that the code in my useeffect is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ticketGuid` at  `list.items.getById(ticketGuid).update()` line which is wrong. Instead of ticketGuid, you have to use the SharePoint default ID of list item.

For Example:

```
const list = sp.web.lists.getByTitle("TicketList");

const i = await list.items.getById(1).update({
  Title: "My New Title",
  Description: "Here is a new description"
});
```

Where 1 is `ID` of list item.

---

The URL should be generated in this format:

```
web/lists/getByTitle('TicketList')/items(1)
```

**Documentation**: [Update items](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/items/#update-items)

---

Payload for multiple selection column should in format:

```
TeamMembers: { results: [10, 12, 15] }
```